# Gulp clean / del behaviour has changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Part of my gulpfile.js

```
const del = require('del');
const chrome_dir = 'build/chrome';
const ff_dir = 'build/firefox';

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del([chrome_dir, ff_dir], cb);
});


gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('build packages', 'JS Backend', 'i18n', 'ExtRes', 'styles', 'JS Content', 'templates');
});
```

worked well.
Then I installed a new system and there maybe got new versions of gulp and del and whatever.
Now gulp stops after cleaning.
I can call all tasks manually, that's working fine.
Could only be a change in the behaviour of del...

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the current version of del & gulp

Comment: gulp: 3.9.0, del: 2.0.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the most important changes on `v2` is that now it returns a *Promise* instead of using a *callback* to handle **async**. From `del` [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/del#delpatterns-options).

You simply have to re-write this part of your code:

```
gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del([chrome_dir, ff_dir], cb);
});
```

like this:

```
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([chrome_dir, ff_dir]);
});
```